# What are the cognitive effects of increasing testosterone levels in men?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, performance, testosterone

I've recently became interested in the effects if testosterone on the cognitive function in men, but cannot find much hard scientific evidence on the subject.

**What are the cognitive effects of increasing testosterone levels in men?**. There's a tremendous amount of anecdotal evidence from body builders, etc, but I'm looking for hard science, where the levels were measured before and after, and the trials were less than a month long.

Some of the claims made about increased testosterone levels seem very interesting, and I would like to know if any of that is true.

- does increasing testosterone levels increase subjective feeling of well being in men?
- does increased testosterone benefit concentration ?
- does increased testosterone benefit non-sexual motivation or ambition?
- does increased testosterone benefit logical/math/engineering endeavors?

Here's what I see on [Wikipedia snippet on testosterone and brain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testosterone#Brain):

> The **literature suggests that attention, memory, and spatial ability
>   are key cognitive functions affected by testosterone in humans**.
>   Preliminary evidence suggests that low testosterone levels may be a
>   risk factor for cognitive decline and possibly for dementia of the
>   Alzheimer's type,[70][71][72][73] a key argument in life extension
>   medicine for the use of testosterone in anti-aging therapies. Much of
>   the literature, however, suggests a curvilinear or even quadratic
>   relationship between spatial performance and circulating
>   testosterone,[74] where both hypo- and hypersecretion (deficient- and
>   excessive-secretion) of circulating androgens have negative effects on
>   cognition.

Answer (score 6):

I've discussed a lot of this recently on my answer to this question: [Are there recent theories on physiognomy?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/5740/4086) In summary, yes.

- Can't remember which of the tons I referenced mentioned well-being, but if you run a search function (`Ctrl F`, or `⌘F` if you don't like good computers) on the text of the freely available articles I provided hyperlinks for, I guarantee you'll find it, and it was a positive relationship with testosterone.
- Testosterone ($T$) might affect concentration, but I'd bet it's not a beneficial effect if so, or at least that it's moderated strongly by context. $T$ relates to spatial intelligence, but also to aggression, which may reflect some effect on impulsivity.
- $T$ affects motivation, but again, I wouldn't call it a benefit, as the specific motives it affects probably aren't optimally healthy to say the least, and every action has its opportunity cost. Specifically, $T$ increases dominance and competitiveness in men, which is probably to say that it increases the [need for power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Need_for_power). It also increases sensation seeking and risk tolerance / decreases risk aversion, which is probably to say that it affects the [behavioral activation and inhibition systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray%27s_biopsychological_theory_of_personality#Behavioral_Inhibition_System). Some evidence suggests testosterone interacts with competitive experiences differently for women.
- For logical/math/engineering problems, $T$ is probably more unequivocally beneficial, because it relates to spatial intelligence.

$T$ is probably most studied in men; I'm not sure effects are similar for women in general. [Estradiol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estradiol) in women may act more like testosterone in men in some ways.  <sub>I can copy content from [my other answer](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/5743/4086) here if desired, or expand on particular points if there is further interest. Please comment if so; I would also welcome collaborative edits.</sub>